# Is it possible to build application with just Windows SDK 8 and .Net 4.5 installed?

Tags: .net, winapi, build, msbuild

I had downloaded and installed [Windows 8 SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/apps/hh852363). But, in the documentation below in the same download page I found the following note:

> **Command-line Build Environment** The Windows SDK no longer ships with a
>   complete command-line build environment. The Windows SDK now requires
>   a compiler and build environment to be installed separately.
>
> By removing the command-line build environment, the Windows SDK no
>   longer ships the following components:
>
> - Windows SDK Platform Toolset
> - Visual C++ Compilers and C Runtime (CRT)
> - Windows SDK Configuration Tool

I suppose, this command-line build environment used to help us build code earlier by just using only Windows SDK and .NET installed in prior versions of Windows SDK. (Pardon me if I am wrong about it).

So, is it possible to build code for us only using Windows SDK 8 and .NET 4.5 installed. If so, how?

**Note:** I don't have any version of Visual Studio installed in this machine

Comment: The missing parts are only relevant to building C and C++ programs.  There is very little point in punishing yourself like this, the Express editions are free.

Comment: @HansPassant, the machine which I am trying this out has a constraint of RAM capacity and HDD space. So VS may not perform well on that and will eat a good amount of my HDD as well. That's the reason I'm trying this way to reduce resource conception.

Comment: What type of project are you trying to build ? From my knowledge - visual studio is using msbuild and project specific tasks and targets to build everything (except few old formats). If you get all required targets and tasks on your machine - you can build whatever project you want using msbuild tool.
And first thing to try right now is to build your current project on current environment. It potentially can be built already.

Comment: @AlexeyShcherbak, What I am trying to build is a csproj and a wixproj to package it. Ya, wixproj may need WIX also installed along with it.

Comment: csproj can be easily built using msbuild.exe, but not wix. Wix is not supported out of the box. But I just found this helpful topic http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/1cc7b91d-1cb4-4850-8f7f-478dd2fc403e/wix-and-tfs-msbuild. 

BTW I didn't tried it so I can't confirm that it'll help or not in your situation.